# Vbscript to search through Microsoft Word files for keywords

Tags: microsoft-word, search, vbscript

I'd like to search through a large number of word files all held in the same folder, searching each document for a keyword.

When a document is identified which contains the keyword the script should output the document file name to a text file report.

So far I have created the following script which searches specified word docs for set terms. This script is obviously hardcoded for specific files, if you could demonstrate how to make it search all `".doc"` files in the folder that would be great. It also does not create the text file report.

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("L:\STSMP00001.docx")
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Find.Forward = True
objSelection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
objSelection.Find.Text = "presentation"

Do While True
    objSelection.Find.Execute
    If objSelection.Find.Found Then
        strWord = objSelection.Text
        strWord = Replace(strWord, "[[", "")
        strWord = Replace(strWord, "]]", "")
        Wscript.Echo strWord
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("L:\STSMP00002.docx")
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Find.Forward = True
objSelection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
objSelection.Find.Text = "presentation"

Do While True
    objSelection.Find.Execute
    If objSelection.Find.Found Then
        strWord = objSelection.Text
        strWord = Replace(strWord, "[[", "")
        strWord = Replace(strWord, "]]", "")
        Wscript.Echo strWord
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet, modified from a [post by Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288555/vbscript-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-based-on-last-modified-date-desc), allows you to specify a folder and then creates a list based on the extension:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objLog = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\out.log", true)
Set list = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
list.Fields.Append "name", 200, 255
'list.Fields.Append "date", 7
list.Open

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\temp").Files
    If (UCase(Right(f.Path,4))=".DOC" or UCase(Right(f.Path,5))=".DOCX") then
        list.AddNew
        list("name").Value = f.Path
        'list("date").Value = f.DateLastModified
        list.Update
    end if
Next

list.MoveFirst
Do Until list.EOF
  WScript.Echo list("name").Value
  objLog.write list("name").Value
  list.MoveNext
Loop

list.Close
objLog.Close
```

Modify the `GetFolder("C:\temp")` with the path where your files are, and the `InStr(f.Path,".txt")` part with the document extension you would like to include. Any files found, for the example, will get written to the screen and to `c:\temp\out.log` Shouldn't be that difficult to include with your code so that you can iterate through a folder and just find the files with .DOC (or .DOCX) on them.

Answer to author's comment below:

The code to get the list of files in folder `c:\temp` starts in the `for each` loop. We look at each file name retrieved, and if the string ".txt" is in the file name, it would be added to the `list` object. You could change the logic of the `if...end if` statement by first changing the `.txt` section to `.doc` and then adding an `or Instr(f.path,".docx")` before the `then` so that both .DOC and .DOCX files are found. As I look at it, I would probably change the `Instr` to include the rightmost 4 and 5 characters of the string, so that only the extension is used. As it stands, if there's a file named "this is my.txt file.pdf" it would be selected as the string `.txt` is found in there. I have made the changes. As it stands, the script should find any .DOC or .DOCX files in folder `c:\temp`

Hope this helps!

Comment: JSanchez please could you point me in the direction of the code which can iterate through the folder looking for the doc/docx files?